# Inherit class with chaining functions

Tags: scala, inheritance, method-chaining

Lets say i have a class with chaining functions

```
class Vehicle {
  protected var position: (Int, Int) = (0, 0)
  def moveLeft(meters: Int): Vehicle = {
    position = position._1 - meters -> position._2
    this
  }

  def moveForward(meters: Int): Vehicle = {
    position = position._1 -> (position._2 + meters)
    this
  }
}
```

so each method returns instance itself

Now i want to inherit Vehicle and add some method to new class

```
class Helicopter extends Vehicle {
  protected var verticalDimension: Int = 0
  def flyIntoTheSky(meters: Int): Helicopter = {
    verticalDimension += meters
    this
  }
}
```

If i will create a new class instance and call any functions from parent, for example

```
new Helicopter().moveLeft(10).moveForward(20)
```

i will not be able to call new class method flyIntoTheSky because methods return type is Vehicle, and Vehicle does not know anything about methods of Helicopter.

2 obvious ways to solve it:
Either using asInstanceOf

```
new Helicopter()
  .moveLeft(10)
  .moveForward(20).asInstanceOf[Helocopter]
  .flyIntoTheSky(10000)
```

either overriding each and avery parental method in new class

Both ways are not looking nice, i would prefer to leave all this type issues to Vehicle class and forget about it, so i found(as i hoped) the solution, rewriting methods like this

```
def moveLeft[T](meters: Int, vehicle: T = this): T = {
  position = position._1 - meters -> position._2
  this.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

so i expected that return type will be taken from method's second parameter vehicle, which always equals to default value "this", and will return the value of current type. But unfortunately

```
new Helicopter().moveLeft(10)
```

still returns value of type Vehicle
res0: Vehicle = Helicopter@1de81c37

So the first question: why it doesn't work as i expected. And the second: is there are any beautiful way to solve this problem

Thank you

PS In google i found this solution in Java
https://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/implementing-chained-methods-in-subclasses/
, but i dont know java and can not translate it in scala

Comment: This is know as the return current type problem. There are two well know solutions, **F-Bounded** polymorphism and **typeclasses**. Check [this](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) for an in-depth discussion of both techniques for this problem. There is a third alternative using **Type members** which is similar to **F-Bounded** but weaker. And finally, for this specific case, since you are mutating a value instead of returning a modified copy _(which should be the ideal)_ I believe you can just use `this.type` as a the return type. So `def moveLeft(...): this.type`.

Comment: Thanks i will read... About mutating a value it is just an example, but anyway immutable state is FP requirements, it's a kind of religion which has its own pro and contra, so there are no real reasons to tell someone that "it should be ideal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the method always returns `this` you can give it return type `this.type`.

```
def moveLeft(meters: Int): this.type = {
  position = position._1 - meters -> position._2
  this
}
```

Comment: So easy? Thanks! But could you explain why my approach didnt work that i could understand scala type mechanism better?

Comment: @DmitryReutov is there a reason for passing `vehicle: T = this` in rewritten moveLeft ? If you do not pass that then  it will  work as `val heli: Helicopter = new Helicopter().moveLeft[Helicopter](10).flyIntoTheSky(100)`

Comment: @asanand, yes, but i dont want to write like this moveLeft[Helicopter], as i mentioned i want to leave it to Vehicle class and forget

Comment: @DmitryReutov Type of `T` is still Vehicle when you call `new Helicopter().moveLeft(10)`. You can get type of T by following this post https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10493 . 
Basically this is how I tested (following the same above link):
`def moveLeft[T](meters: Int, vehicle: T = this)(implicit m: ClassManifest[T]): T = {
      position = position._1 - meters -> position._2
      println(m.erasure)
      this.asInstanceOf[T]
    }`

Comment: @asanand, strange, i cant get sense. If this.type refers to Helicopter why def moveLeft[T](meters: Int, vehicle: T = this): T refers still to Vehicle

Answer (score 2):

Addressing comment

> strange, i cant get sense. If this.type refers to Helicopter why def
>   moveLeft[T](meters: Int, vehicle: T = this): T refers still to Vehicle

Note that `this` and `this.type` exist in two separate worlds, although `this.type` is "encroaching" on the value world as I will attempt to explain bellow. The former is a *value* whilst latter is a *type*, although a special kind of type. The type of expression `this` is not `this.type`, instead according to [SLS](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#this-and-super):

> The expression `this`... stands for the object being defined by the innermost
>   template or compound type **enclosing** the reference. If this is a
>   compound type, the type of `this` is that compound type. If it is a
>   template of a class or object definition with simple name , the type
>   of this is the same as the type of `.this`.

The innermost enclosing class of `this` in `def moveLeft[T](meters: Int, vehicle: T = this): T` is in fact `Vehicle`, therefore the static type of `this` is `Vehicle`.

Now consider type `this.type`:

```
    this           .           type
     |             |            |
    value     dot notation     type 
   \                               /
    -------------------------------
                   |
           value-dependent type
```

Notice the dot notation `.` which is used on a *value*, that is, if `this` was not a value then we would use `#` notation like so `this#type`. However it is indeed a value, which means type `type` **depends** on value `this`. Now, what value does it depend on? Well, no pun intended, it depends. Given the expression `new Helicopter()` it depends on the value (object) referred to by `new Helicopter()`, whilst given the expression `new Car()` it depends on the value referred to by expression `new Car()`. Important to understand here is that despite the fact that now `this.type` seems to be "changing" depending on a value, it is still a **static** type proper, meaning there is no runtime type-checking shenanigans.

I believe the source of confusion stems from the fact that we know, given `new Helicopter()`, in both cases, `this` refers to object of class `Helicopter` at runtime, however the key is to understand what static types can compiler determine, which in turn yields what members are invokable. In the case of `this.type` the compiler can determine the narrowest possible value-dependent [singleton type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html) uniquely inhabited by this very value.

---

As a side-note here is my attempt using shapeless lenses:

```
import shapeless._
case class Position(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double = 0)

sealed trait Vehicle
case class Car(p: Position) extends Vehicle
case class Plane(p: Position) extends Vehicle

object Vehicle {
  implicit val carPosLens = lens[Car].p
  implicit val planePosLens = lens[Plane].p
}

implicit class Move[T <: Vehicle](v: T) {
  def moveX(d: Double)(implicit ev: Lens[T, Position]): T = ev.modify(v)(p => p.copy(x = p.x + d))
  def moveY(d: Double)(implicit ev: Lens[T, Position]): T = ev.modify(v)(p => p.copy(y = p.y + d))
}

implicit class Fly[T <: Plane](v: T) {
  def moveZ(d: Int)(implicit ev: Lens[T, Position]): T = ev.modify(v)(p => p.copy(z = p.z + d))
}

Plane(Position(0,0,0)).moveX(42).moveY(-3.142).moveZ(11)
Car(Position(0,0)).moveX(1)
```

which outputs

```
res0: Plane = Plane(Position(42.0,-3.142,11.0))
res1: Car = Car(Position(1.0,0.0,0.0))
```